# JSON data not working using fs in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to parse a json file and get some errors. It is in a directory under my js file with the fs in a folder called "recipes" with 3 json files all representing a seperate object.
Here's the json of all 3 that are similar:

```
{
    "ingredients":
    [
        {"name":"Crab","unit":"Tsp","amount":3},
        {"name":"Peas","unit":"Cup","amount":12},
        {"name":"Basil","unit":"Tbsp","amount":10},
        {"name":"Cumin","unit":"Liter","amount":3},
        {"name":"Salt","unit":"Tbsp","amount":1}
    ],
    
    "name":"Boiled Crab with Peas",
    "preptime":"13",
    "cooktime":"78",
    "description":"A boring recipe using Crab and Peas",
    "id":"b0e347d5-9428-48e5-a277-2ec114fc05a0"
}
```

My code is this: It gives an unexpected JSON position 1

```
fs.readdirSync("./recipes").forEach(file =>{
    //let rec = JSON.parse(file);
    console.log(JSON.parse(file))
  })
```

Comment: you need to pass the contents of file as string in `JSON.parse(fileContentsString)` It cannot read a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readdirSync` could return name string, binary, or dirent object. Neither is the file contents. The custom `readFiles` is what you need.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const ROOT_DIR = './contents'

const readFiles = (dir, cb) => {
  try {
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file =>{
      fs.readFile(path.join(dir, file), 'utf-8', cb)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Failed to open the directory ${e.path} `)
  }
}

readFiles(ROOT_DIR, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Failed to read file: ${err.path}`)
  }
  console.log(JSON.parse(data))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below solution. I am not sure if I correctly passed the file path in `readFile` method, but it should work if the path is correct.

[See this post](https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodejs-read-write-json-files)

```
fs.readdirSync("./recipes").forEach(file => {
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => { // not sure if file is the filePath

    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error reading file from disk: ${err}`);
    } else {

        // parse JSON string to JSON object
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));

    }

});
});
```